# How do I create a custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a website for a gym company. I have different gym locations. Within each gym location I have pages for classes and facilities.

What I want to do is create a section in the back end of wordpress for each location. So below pages tab there is a section named for each location of the gym. When you click on that location, it opens up with classes and a tab for facilities. Once classes is clicked on, I want the user to be able to add a title for the class and a description. I then want them to be able to add a video. The title and description will float left and the video will float right with a line below it separating it from the next class.

I would like facilities to work very much the same except they will add an image instead of video.

Is this possible with this plugin? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you with what you need:

[Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/)

As for how everything is styled, the rules would be defined in the Theme's CSS.

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently using that plugin but I'm not sure how to set it up so that it's a tab rather than just custom fields appearing in pages. I want the user to be able to keep adding new classes and facilities

Comment: It also allows you to add Custom Post Types. The option is right there in your dashboard under Types->Custom Types and Taxonomies.

Comment: I'm struggling a little bit. I've created the custom post type but now I need to create something within it called classes. Within classes there needs to be an add new with WYSIWYG and to add an image. If I create a taxonomy those features aren't available. Do you know how I would do this?